# timestamp like 6.3527482515083E+17

Tags: c#, php

I'm getting via WSDL from C# application timestamp number like

```
6.3527482515083E+17
6.3527482515047E+17
6.352748251638E+17
6.3527482514463E+17
```

All are the times in the past (this year, probably)

I think that's is the datetime counted from YEAR ZERO. I try to count up seconds from ZERO and get someting about 63537810544. But this is not exact, because missing leap years.

exists in PHP any function how to get UNIX timestamp ??? or convert it to STRING datetime ???
I get values via WSDL so I can't reformat it on source...

Comment: There's a big difference between 10**10 and 10**17. Unless it's counting _tenths of microseconds,_ you're way off.

Comment: I already found that http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/749/converting-datetime-ticks-to-a-unix-timestamp-and-back-in-php

Comment: `DateTime` values internally use Ticks, which is the number of 100-nanosecond units since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D.

Comment: I have provided an answer and some sample code that should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

They are in 100 nanosecond ticks (1/10,000,000 of a second) from 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001. This information can be found in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx).

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million ticks in a second.
>   The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001, which represents DateTime.MinValue. It does not include the number of ticks that are attributable to leap seconds.

The magic constant that represents the number of 100ns ticks between 12:00:00 midnight January 1 0001 and 12:00:00 midnight January 1 1970 (Unix epoch time) is `62135596800000000`. So if you subtract that from your numbers you get 100ns ticks since beginning of Unix Epoch time. Divide that by 10,000,000 and you get seconds. And that is usable in PHP. Sample code below to demonstrate (`unixepoch` is in seconds):

```
<?php
$msdatetime = 6.3527482515083E+17;
$unixepoch = ($msdatetime - 621355968000000000)/10000000 ;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixepoch);
?>
```

Output:

```
2014-02-08 11:55:15
```

I found this constant listed on this [helpful site](http://shafiqissani.wordpress.com/2010/09/30/how-to-get-the-current-epoch-time-unix-timestamp/) dealing with the problem of getting unix epoch time from other formats.